# How parse li class in a ListView Using Jsoup

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist, jsoup

I am parsing a web page http://abcsur.info/clasificados/inmuebles/casas, the page is refreshed and change every week. I want to display the ads on [li class#li.list-group-items]. 
 [image]

My idea is to add this li classes to a List View. After search in several sites, i write this code, but the app crash (NullPointerException)

```
public class Casas extends Activity {

public Casas(){}
// URL Address
String url = "http://abcsur.info/clasificados/inmuebles/casas";
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.casas);

            new Title().execute();


}

// Title AsyncTask
private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    List<String> items;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Casas.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("ABC sur");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements li = document.select("ul.list-group");
            List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Element item : li) {
                items.add(item.text());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Casas.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        lv.setAdapter(adaptador);

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Any idea?

Logcat

```
   Process: info.androidhive.abcsur, PID: 2923
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int   java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
        at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:487)
        at info.androidhive.abcsur.InmueblesFolder.Casas$Title.onPostExecute(Casas.java:92)
        at info.androidhive.abcsur.InmueblesFolder.Casas$Title.onPostExecute(Casas.java:49)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

After Update (Works!)

```
 public class Casas extends Activity {

public Casas(){}
// URL Address
String url = "http://abcsur.info/clasificados/inmuebles/casas";
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.casas);

            new Title().execute();


}

// Title AsyncTask
private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String lii;
    List<String> items;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Casas.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("ABC sur");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements li = document.select("li.list-group-items");
            items = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Element item : li) {
                items.add(item.text());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Casas.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        lv.setAdapter(adaptador);
        adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

And the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need those text which is inside li? and also provide logcat.

Comment: Yes, those texts inside li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `List<String> items;` already before `onPreExecute`. Also you declared and initiated the same `ArrayList` in `doInBackground`.

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
```

When you add `items` to ArrayAdapter on `onPostExecute()`, it refers to the top `ArrayList` items **NOT** the ArrayList `items` in `doInBackground`.

> Since it refers the top `ArrayList` which you haven't initiated, that gives you the error java.util.List.size() on a null object reference.

So, just change,

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to,

```
items = new ArrayList<String>();
```

in `doInBackground`.

Comment: Ok. Now there is no error. But the text doesnt appear in the listview (the ones in the li class)

Comment: call `adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();` in `onPostExecute` before `mProgressDialog.dismiss();` . If it doesn't work, you need to post your xml layout code.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: The ListView still empty

Comment: Post the updated code and layout in question itself with heading `After Update`.

Comment: Its work!!, The only things I have to fix is to add a line betwwen each ad.